# express application upload to beanstalk aborts the deployment process

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What I am trying to do is create zip folder of the application and upload it to elastic beanstalk. But somehow it fails and gives me the following error:

```
[Instance: 'name] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED).../opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install raise e subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.12.2-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

The package.json for that project is as shown below:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@google/maps": "^0.4.5",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.199.0",
        "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
        "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
        "busboy-body-parser": "^0.3.0",
        "describe": "^1.2.0",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "express": "^4.13.3",
        "express-validator": "^3.2.1",
        "fcm-push": "^1.1.2",
        "file-system": "^2.2.2",
        "firebase-admin": "^4.2.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
        "mailgun-js": "^0.13.1",
        "mongoose": "^4.8.4",
        "morgan": "^1.8.1",
        "multer": "^1.3.0",
        "node-schedule": "^1.2.5",
        "nodemailer": "^3.1.4",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
        "s3-image-uploader": "^1.0.7",
        "sqs-consumer": "^3.8.0",
        "stripe": "^4.17.0",
        "twilio": "^3.7.0",
        "useragent": "^2.2.1",
        "utf8": "^2.1.2",
        "uuid": "^3.0.1",
        "winston": "^2.3.1",
        "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.4.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.1.2",
        "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
        "mocha": "^3.4.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
    }
```

What am I missing in my deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.12.2-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild'] if failing.

Running NPM as part of the deploy process can be problematic especially if you have not shrink wrapped the dependancies.

You may be able to see the specific package install problem on the instance in /var/log/eb-activity.log (eb ssh to the instance)

Can you run `npm production` locally with an empty node_modules directory?

Comment: When I uploaded the zip folder, it already had `node_modules` directory with necessary packages